# principal curvature of hypersurface in Rn

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $\Sigma$ is a hypersurface in $R^n$, let $x$ be a fixed point on $\Sigma$ and $\nu$ be the unit normal at $x$ to the hypersurface. I would like to know what the following limit would be.
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow x, y\in \Sigma} \frac{(x-y)\cdot \nu(x)}{|x-y|^2}.$$

I feel like it is the largest principal curvature at $x$. Is there any rigorious proof for it?

Comment: Why don't you write down something that looks like the definition of the derivative $d\nu(x)$?

Comment: I think I understand it now. The fraction is actually the reciprocal of the radius of the sphere touching at x and passing through y.

Comment: I didn't pay close enough attention. What I suggested was irrelevant. You are sort of on the right track, but I will say that the limit rarely exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SKETCH of an ANSWER**: Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the principal directions at $x$, with corresponding principal curvatures $\kappa_1,\dots,\kappa_n$. Then we can think of $\Sigma$ locally as a graph over the tangent plane at $x$: Indeed, using the coordinates corresponding to the orthonormal basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$, it is the graph of $$f(t_1,\dots,t_n) = \tfrac12\sum \kappa_i t_i^2 + o(\|t\|^2).$$
That is, points $y$ near $x$ are of the form
$$y=x+\sum t_ie_i + \left(\tfrac12\sum \kappa_it_i^2 + \dots\right)\nu(x).$$
So it looks like you're looking at the limit
$$\lim_{(t_1,\dots,t_n)\to (0,\dots,0)} \frac12\frac{\sum \kappa_i t_i^2}{\sum t_i^2}.$$
This limit will not exist unless $x$ is an umbilic point, i.e., all $\kappa_i$ are equal.

Comment: You could reposition the surface so that the tangent plane is $t^{n+1}=0$ and write